# Spacing between borders, I can't remove it

Tags: css

```
<div id="menuNav">
    <ul id="menuNav-ul">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have a JSFiddle that I've made here:

http://jsfiddle.net/agzF5/

If you hover over the menu items that aren't the first of type you'll notice there is some strange margin appearing after where the border would be if it were set, I was wondering as to how I can remove that?

Matt

Comment: `background: lightgrey repeat-x;` really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**JSFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewhaining/agzF5/4/)

You had your list items as display:inline-block;

I've floated them left, added display:block; and changed some properties on the wrapping element. so it still contains the floated elements, see below.

```
#menuNav-ul {
    background: lightgrey repeat-x;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border-bottom: 2px solid darkgrey;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#menuNav-ul li {
    display: block;
    border-right: 1px solid #bfbfbf;    
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
html, body{margin:0;}
```

to the top, body alone should probably work as well..

Answer (score 0):

You're setting your `LI` elements to be `display:inline-block` which means they will have a *inline whitespace* space between them (usually ~4px).

## 3 solutions:

**1. [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/agzF5/5/)**

add `font-size:0;` to the `UL`
reset the font size **to px** for the `LI` elements

**2.** don't add `display:inline-block;` but `float:left;` your `LI` elements

**3. (not recommended)** add a -4px margin-left to your LI elements

---

P.S: an additional suggestion is not to style (colors, borders etc) you `LI` elements. Treat them like simple positioned containers for your styled `<a>` elements.

Comment: Is it really a good idea to use floats instead of the inline-block function?

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered with good solutions.

I wanted to leave this here in case it helps someone though.

The reason for this is that there is whitespace in your markup (totally fine), which inline-block renders as spaces.

If you are working with inline-block elements, you can to set the font-size of the parent to 0, then explicitly set the font-size of the child elements as a workaround for this.

Answer (score 0):

Well the simple solution is to add comment between your li items:

```
<div id="menuNav">
    <ul id="menuNav-ul">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li><!--
        --><li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Check it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/agzF5/7/